# Java AES decryption from .txt file only works in IDE

Tags: java, encryption, jar, aes

Im doing a simple Java program which reads AES encrypted text from a .txt file and decrypts it to print it into a textbox. I tested it out inside my IDE and everything worked. However if I build a .jar and open it up no text is added into the textbox.
It does find the .txt file, it does read the text but I think theres a problem with the decryption part.

```
    public String decryptAES(String input, String key, String initVector){
    try {
      IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

      byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(input));

      return new String(original);
```

Especially the line `byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(input));` could maybe be the one causing the problem. I just cant work out why it wont work with a standalone .jar.

Edit: I tried to step by step debug the jar myself. Printing stack trace to MsgBoxes and adding comments and whatnot to see where it stops. No stack traces were shown to me. It seems to stop right before this mentioned line:

> byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(input));

Edit2: Encryption works just fine. Also outside IDE. Heres the part:

```
public String encryptAES(String input, String key, String initVector) 
  {
    try {
      IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());

      return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
```

Comment: "could maybe" isn't helpful :(  Q: Exactly how are you debugging outside of the IDE? "System.out.println()" trace statements?  [jdb](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html)?  Other?

Comment: Can you show the encryption part as well?

Comment: And the stack trace is?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I didnt get any. Did it just in case

Comment: Time to start debugging.

Comment: Print out "input" before you call "doFinal()".  EXAMPLE: `byte[] inputBytes = input.getString(); System.out.println("input=" + input + ", inputBytes.length=" + inputBytes.length); byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);`

Comment: I bet that OP is fetching byte content in some "relative" way

Comment: @kamino how do you know that file is actually read? I see no confirmation nor proof of that in code nor question.